# ASP.NET can't create Windows Event Log even as Administrator

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, error-handling

I'm working on an ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2013 and as part of the main error routine, I want it to store the errors in a Windows Event Log. However, every time I run the code, the log never gets created even when I run Visual Studio as Administrator. Would turning off UAC fix this? Code is below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public static void ErrorRoutine(Exception e, string obj, string method)
    {
        EventLog.Delete("LogName");  // uncomment this line to delete log
        EventLog log = new EventLog();
        log.Source = "SourceName";
        log.Log = "LogName";

        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            log.WriteEntry("Error in Models, object = " + obj + ", method = " + method + ", inner exception = " +
                e.InnerException.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            throw e.InnerException;
        }
        else
        {
            log.WriteEntry("Error in Models, object = " + obj + ", method = " + method + ", message = " + e.Message,
                EventLogEntryType.Error);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Edit: I get that this is probably not best practice but this project is actually an assignment for college and this is the exact code we were told to write, as well as being told to run VS as Administrator. I just need to find a way to make work really.

Comment: have you looked at any of the MSDN documentation on this  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzwc042w(v=vs.110).aspx
have you tried getting the e.Message instead..? other examples can be found here as well [EventLog](http://www.dotnetperls.com/eventlog)

Comment: This is not an activity that I would ever be happy for my webserver to have permission to do. Are you running in IIS? The elevation level of Visual Studio won't give your app more elevation in this case. If you run in the dev server, you *may* have more luck, as it is spawned at the elevation level of VS.

Comment: have you thought about writing to an ErrorLog on the Database side just create a small table with 4 or 5 columns and write to the database.. also wrap that code around a `try{}catch{}` and do some proper exception handling / report / logging there too..